# Removing [] and "" from a pandas column

Tags: pandas

I have a column in a pandas df:

```
["text","text2"]
["bla","bla","bla"]
```

What's the best way to remove those `[]` and `""` to get:

```
text,text2
bla,bla,bla
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would achieve the substitutions you need - using `re.sub`:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"c1":["[\"text\",\"text2\"]","[\"bla\",\"bla\",\"bla\"]"]})

df["c1"].apply(lambda x:re.sub('[\["\]]', "", x))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0     text,text2
1    bla,bla,bla
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.column.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x).replace('"',''))
```

Comment: i still have the [] and got [t,e,x,t,t,e,x,t,2]

Comment: ah then you don't have lists but strings which look like lists. you can us `df.column.str.replace('[\[\]\"]', regex=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Try replace everything except alphanumerics and comma

```
df['c1'].str.replace('[^\w,]','', regex=True)

0     text,text2
1    bla,bla,bla
Name: c1, dtype: object
```